# Connecting through VPN breaks xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, vpn

I am currently set up using xdebug, PhpStorm & Vagrant.

It works perfect, but when I am connected to the internet through a VPN, the debug page never loads, it hangs on connecting to the page.

Specifically I click Run > Debug, and Firefox browser opens and the page is blank, the tab says "Connecting..." with the spinning icon, the bottom left says "Waiting for {page address}...". PhpStorm gives no indication it is waiting for anything, it looks like it is connected in debug mode.

If I wait for about 5 minutes or more, sometimes the page does load, but it is unusable for debugging purposes, and if I click a link/refresh the page, again it is 5 minutes.

Any idea why being connected through VPN would break it like this?

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, can we get a few more details about your setup?

Without knowing your specific setup, I'm going to guess that the remote PHP app may not be able to connect to port 9000 on your laptop.

Before starting your debug session, you might try setting up a reverse tunnel to allow your remote host to talk to port 9000 on your laptop.

From a command line on your laptop you would do something like the following :

> ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9000:laptop-IP:9000  remoteUser@webServerIP
>
> For example,   ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9000:192.168.1.29:9000  user500@192.168.0.100

In the above example, your laptop (192.168.1.29) will be logged into the remote server (192.168.0.100) as user500 and will be able to see via the `netstat` command that it's listening for connections on port 9000 :

> user500@192.168.0.100$ netstat -natep | grep 9000
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      500        5189077    -
> tcp        0      0 ::1:9000                    :::*                   LISTEN      500        5189076    -

Now you should be able to initiate a debug session with PhpStorm by setting `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` on your remote server in php.ini .

Similarly, initiating a php debug session from the command line while logged into the remote server would look like this -

> php -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_enable=1  -dxdebug.remote_autostart=1  my_php_code.php

I'm running linux / CentOS on both my laptop and remote server.